# Handling "incompatibily" overloaded names in Cppcheck

Tags: c++, overloading, static-analysis, cppcheck, false-positive

I'm stuck with a "conflict" between with AnsiString`s` sprintf`member function and Cppcheck's built-in`sprintf` knowledge.

In cases like this,

```
const char* name = "X";
int version = 1;

return AnsiString().sprintf("%s.H%02d", name, version); // <-- HERE
```

I'm getting this warning in the Cppcheck GUI

> Id: wrongPrintfScanfArgNum
>
> Summary: sprintf format string requires 0 parameters but 1 is given.
>
> Message: sprintf format string requires 0 parameters but 1 is given.

which shows that Cppcheck is talking about the `sprintf` *function*, but I'm using a *member function* of the VCL class `AnsiString` with the same name.

As to get rid of this false positive, I could use

- an inline suppression: `// cppcheck-suppress wrongPrintfScanfArgNum`
- an intermediate variable: `AnsiString result; result.printf(...); return result;`
- the `sprintf` *function*, which means handle the buffer space manually

But all these options work local, and make the code harder to read/maintain.

**How can I teach Cppcheck to differentiate between overloaded names?**

---

**Edits:**

- I wrote override, but meant overloading, I corrected that in the current text.
- added literal initialization of variables, which is important for `name`

Comment: Perhaps raise a bug with the actual author of the tool? This seems like the wrong place to ask.

Comment: BTW, editorial nitpick incoming: you emphasise `sprintf` being a _function_, but in fact your `AnsiString::sprintf` is a _function_ also. That it is a member function (what you are calling a "method", though this terminology does not exist in C++) does not make it not a function. The key point is that it's not `std::sprintf` (or `::sprintf`).

Comment: Also, as an aside, `AnsiString` is poorly designed. Sure, CppCheck should be smarter than this, but it could be equally confusing for a human. Why re-use the name "`sprintf`" and change its parameters? Silly. I suggest you stick to standard technologies and well-regarded third-party libraries only; not Turbo C++ nonsense!

Comment: Hah, that's weird; I'd opened a few tabs of new questions as well as notifications on old questions. After commenting here, I moved to the next in my list, on which I'd received an upvote. There I found lots of comments and edits from you from 2014 :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit (concerning *`wrong place to ask`*) well, sometimes it's not a bug, but lack of documentation (or reading skills), I expected that overriden functions should be a problem for naive analysis approaches but I know that Cppcheck doesn't check on a simplistic lexical level, so I shared my problem here, hoping someone else had already a working solution...

Comment: A great alternative to sprintf in any form is `boost::format` IMHO. You get the advantages of readability and automatic memory management.

Comment: Of course, it's not overriding, but overloading. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.

Yes I agree this should be reported in http://trac.cppcheck.net. Looks like bugs.

I can see 2 bugs.

The AST does not show proper type information for the 'AnsiString()' even when I add a AnsiString class.

The Library should not match sprintf in that code. It is clear that some method is called.

Comment: It really has to do with **the name `sprintf`**, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39343710/2932052)/[bug report](http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/7726)

Answer (score 1):

It really is a bug.<sup>[1]</sup> Cppcheck 1.75 is *smart* in checking format strings, but obviously only in some cases, one of them is the **second parameter of every function called `printf`**, so the problem has nothing to do with `AnsiString::sprintf` but with every alternate implementation.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> 
[#7726 (False positive: format string checked for every function called 'sprintf') – Cppcheck](http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/7726)